# Custom attrs parameter used in styles.xml

Tags: android

I have a set of custom Android layout parameters defined in attrs.xml. Now I would like to use some tags in my styles.xml file.

At the moment I get this error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'custom:tag'
```

I have tried declaring custom XML namespace as follows:

```
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.project"
>
```

hoping, that the same logic used in every layout declaration can be applied here, but with no success.

Comment: please post code that is in styles.xml

Comment: `<style name="my_style"> <item name="custom:tag">some_value</item> </style>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The XML namespace mechanism is used to namespace tags and attributes. When you define a style like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.project">

    <style name="my_style"> <item name="custom:tag">some_value</item> </style>

</resources>
```

you are trying to apply XML namespacing to an attribute *value*, which won't work. In this case, you should specify the package name directly, like this:

```
    <style name="my_style"> <item name="com.my.project:tag">some_value</item> </style>
```

Now Android will be able to resolve where the attribute is defined.

Comment: ok, what if there are some tags with the same name in different namespaces?

Comment: That is a very good question. After some further investigation I realized that my previous answer was incomplete, please see updated answer.

Comment: and as I understood according namespace should be referenced in layout xml? that works for me only in this case

Comment: If you use the `style` attribute in layout.xml to reference a style that contains an item with `custom:tag`, you don't need a `xmlns:custom` declaration in layout.xml. You only need to declare `xmlns:custom` in layout.xml if you use tags or attributes from the `custom` namespace in layout.xml. (I hope I understood your question correctly, please forgive me if that was not the case.)

Comment: I ment xml namespace reference in root tag of layout file.

Comment: @MartinNordholts How can you state that using namespacing in an attribute value won't work? Consider just the following:     <style name="MyCustomTheme" ...>
      <item name="(!!!)android:windowBackground">@color/my_custom_color</item>

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution did not work for me, but it shed some light upon the situation.

The custom attributes are resolved and can be referenced in a global project's package name, like "com.ltst.project". Even if you have multiple modules (with the same base package name) the resources would be resolved in a project's package name.

So for me it was enough to just omit any prefixes for custom attributes in a style.

Custom attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="SampleView">
    <attr name="sample_color" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Style:

```
<style name="SampleStyle">
    <item name="sample_color">@color/sample_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link

`xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

and define the prefix for each tag as app